# Implicit function theorem - Tangent planes to an Ellipsoid

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

I have an ellipsoid, whose equation is $ \frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{y^2}{9}+\frac{z^2}{4} = 1$ and a plane whose equation is $ x + y + z = 0$.
The goal of this question is to find the tangent planes to the Ellipsoid which are parallel to the plane.

First of all, I do understand that we will get the equations of 2 planes, due to the symmetry of the ellipsoid.

Then, I also know that if we want to find parallel planes, they need to have the same normal vector, $(1,1,1)$. So, I know that the equation of the planes will be somthing like this: $x+y+z+d=0$.

It asks to solve this problem by the implicit function theorem, but despite knowing that with this theorem we can find the normal vector to the surface, I don't know how to proceed.

What shall I do next?

EDIT: Thank you José Carlos for your comment, the equation that I provided was not complete. It is now.

Comment: That definition of the ellipsoid makes no sense. It should be $\frac{x^2}3+\frac{y^2}9+\frac{z^2}4=k$ for some $k>0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The normal vector to the plane, $(1,1,1)$ must be parallel to the gradient vector, $(\frac{2x}3,\frac{2y}9,\frac{2z}4)$. This forms a system of two equations in three unknowns, i.e. of a straight line. It intersects the ellipsoid twice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that you obtained the gradient vector by using the implicit function theorem.
But why is it necessary to do a system of equations with 2 unknowns? Why couldn't I say that $ \frac{2x}{3} = 1$ and therefore $x= \frac{3}{2}$?

I understand that that is not correct, but why?

Comment: @ORapaz: I said *parallel*, I didn't say equal to.

Comment: Ok, and what are the implications of that?

Comment: @ORapaz: review your previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

@Yves, sorry there's something I am not understanding.

If the normal vector is parallel to the gradient, (and I understand that it is), we conclude that:

$1*k = \frac{2x}{3}$

$1*k = \frac{2y}{9}$

$1*k = \frac{2z}{4}$

And from now on, how do we get a system of 2 equations and 3 variables?